# Does the interior of Pascal's triangle contain three consecutive integers?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, binomial-coefficients, conjectures

This question [defeated Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4811425/398708), so I am posting it here.

Consider the interior of Pascal's triangle: the triangle without numbers of the form $\binom{n}{0},\binom{n}{1},\binom{n}{n-1},\binom{n}{n}$.

[A006987](https://oeis.org/A006987/b006987.txt) (which is described [here](https://oeis.org/A006987)) is a list of the smallest $10000$ numbers in the interior of Pascal's triangle, omitting repetitions. It contains $15$ instances of two consecutive integers. It contains only [one instance](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4810786/398708) of integers separated by $2$. But it does not contain three consecutive integers. So I wonder:

> Does the interior of Pascal's triangle contain three consecutive integers?

Conjecture 3.1 of [Binomial Collisions and Near Collisions](https://www.semanticscholar.org/reader/8c98acc207e74033a5e9bc8832d95d0b3b027013) is the conjecture that a list contained in that paper is the complete list of binomials that differ by $1$. If this conjecture is true, this would imply that there are no three consecutive binomial coefficients. But even if this conjecture is unresolved, there might be a way to show that there are no three consecutive binomial coefficients. Maybe proof by contradiction, or a combinatorial argument?

Comment: The linked page ("Here") seems to contain 58 numbers, not 10000.  But that list of 10000 is at https://oeis.org/A006987/b006987.txt .  Also that paper "Binomial ..." is actually at https://www.semanticscholar.org/reader/8c98acc207e74033a5e9bc8832d95d0b3b027013.

Comment: @DanielAsimov I have edited.